# Laravel Eager Loading on nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have one parent model with a child relationship that I'm trying to order by another relationship with the child.

```
Plan
-- Items
--- Details
```

Plan to items is one to many relationship. Items to Details is one to one relationship. I want the Items to be ordered by a field that's set in the details like a title for example. [I was thinking that it would look something like in this article.](https://medium.com/@sander3/laravel-nested-eager-loading-contraints-9742c2dac4b9)

```
Plan::with([
  'items.details' => function ($query) {
      $query->orderBy('title', 'asc');
}])
->findOrFail(1);
```

It doesn't work. I have seen a lot of ways on how to add it to the Parent (Plan) model, but I want to order a relationship--not the parent especially since it's only 1 Plan. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I can't wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `title` is from another table `details`, the `items` and the `details`'s relationship is one-to-one, you can use `leftjoin` like this:

```php
Plan::with([
  'items' => function ($query) {
      $query->leftjoin('details', 'details.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
            ->select('items.*', 'details.title')
            ->orderBy('title', 'asc');
}])
->findOrFail(1);
```

Comment: Gah! That was it. I was so close. I kept doing joins on the parent model. I just couldn't figure out how to do a join in an nested relationship. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone else will run into this issue. The answer that TsailKoga did work, but the collection were interesting. Like the relationships got pushed to parent. For example.

```
Plan (parent)
-- Items 
--- Details
```

All the Details attributes became part of the items. It worked but wasn't quite the result I wanted. I tried doing some funky `usort`, but once you convert a collection to an array to use with usort, you lose all of the tools that goes along with collections/eloquent. I found a way that didn't require anything fancy. Collections have a `sortBy` method. All I had to do is something like `$plan->items->sortBy('details.title')` and viola. Plan Items were sorted by title. Days of work for 1 line of code.

I hope this helps someone else out.